# Can I use same URL key for both the Product and Category?

Tags: magento2.2.3, redirect-url

I'm facing an issue with redirecting the Category page. We are using the same URL key for both the Category and Product. When I click the link which should be redirected to Category but it's not doing that, instead, it's redirecting to the Product page.

So, I want to know whether we can use the same URL key for both the Category and Product page.

Please comment.

Looking forwarding to your reply.

Comment: no, you can't use it. It should be unique, url key once assigned should not be used in other products or categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at catalog rewrite. you can find both url there. You can find path also.

Generally magento add path with url key. So it should work with same url. But some how it is not working for you then you can use category url for access product like

http://www.your-domain.com/category-url/product-url.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why the URL won't redirect to the Category Page?

Comment: In admin panel go to Marketing -> URL rewrites page.
Check Request path and target path column. So you will get idea

Comment: I have checked Marketing -> URL rewrites page and see that the category page has a product that why it's showing the product page instead of the category page. I have tried to edit the URL for category page but it's showing the "Request Path for Specified Store already exists." Please comment.

Comment: Try to use category url in product url like i mention as above.
So for product request path becomes category-url/product-url
category url request path is category-url

I think it may work

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can not use the same url for category and product.

It's not only about the categories and products.
You can not use the same url at any other section whether it is a category page, a product page or any cms page.